# Load Gazebo World into rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I just would like to know if it is possible to load a gazebo world or parts of it (Gazebo Models) into **rviz** directly?

Without loading and spawning the robots (robot_descriptions) in launch files before hand?

I am currently using Indigo and Gazebo 2. I guess there is no fast way to do that as gazebo only publishes these topics:

```
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
```

Best,
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290718/load-gazebo-world-into-rviz/) by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2018-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The typical answer to this is "no", as RViz does not support loading `.sdf` files.

However, there is at least one package (that I know of) that implements a 'trick': [gazebo2rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo2rviz). From the packages wiki page:

> This package contains nodes to automatically import all entities simulated in a ROS-enabled Gazebo instance into rviz through the TF and Marker plugin.

I'm not sure how well supported it still is (or which specific versions of Gazebo are supported), but it would seem to do what you ask for.

> I just would like to know if it is possible to load a gazebo world or parts of it (Gazebo Models) into **rviz** directly?

Note that technically this is not an answer (as the answer is really "no"), but `gazebo2rviz` provides a convenient work-around (if it still works).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-09**:
Related question: #q217324.

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2018-05-11**:
Thanks I check that gazebo2rviz package